# To increment the value whenever the parameter crosses the threshold in power BI using DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am using DirectQuery in Power BI and I want to create a measure for calculating the number of occurrences a particular parameter has crossed its threshold (say 150). If it has crossed twice till now , the value should be 2.
I am a newbie, if anybody could help it would be great!

The data set looks like (with threshold 150)

```
Parameter | Value | Count 
A         | 240   | 1
A         | 245   | 2
A         | 110   | 2
A         | 160   | 3
```

Answer (score 1):

What have you tried so far?

A simple measure like the following should give you what you need:

```
CALCULATE(COUNT('Table'[Value]), 'Table'[Value] > 150)
```

Comment: I was trying something like x + 1 = x kind of a loop since I code using Python more.